# SessionFactory is null with Spring 4 and Hibernate 4

Tags: java, spring

When I try to save data to DB the `SessionFactory` is `null`. Find the code below.

**Spring configuration**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, DAO -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.service.jaxws" />

<!-- Getting Database properties -->
<!-- <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" /> -->

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- DataSource -->
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hrms"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.service.jaxws"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**Repository Bean**

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  public void addUser(UserBO user) {        
    if (sessionFactory != null) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Null");
    }       
  }
}
```

When debugging each and every time the `SessionFactory` is `null`. Could anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Thanks in advance
Serin

Comment: Can the UserDAO be autowired in other beans? Does that work?

Comment: No Matt. At first i have tried with auto wiring the UserDao but at that time i got the below exception ERROR [org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Method invocation failed with exception: null: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

Comment: So, how do you access the ``UserDAO`` ? Where is the code/class that calls ``UserDao.addUser()`` ?

Comment: What package is your Repository in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt the issue has been resolved. The main problem was with the @Autowired. it was not working as expected. I tried this in my @Webservice class. After using the extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport it is working properly. Anyway thanks for your support.